# returning nothing from a list comprehension

Tags: for-loop, elixir, list-comprehension, return-value, side-effects

Suppose you have the following list comprehension:

```erlang
for i <- 2..n |> Enum.map(&(&1*&1+ &1), i <= :math.sqrt(n), do
  Refrigerator.put(pid, i, "this is my food")
end
```

Is there an idiomatic way to disable returning of the resultant comprehension?

For situations like this, I'm not interested in the returned comprehension, but the `for` makes producing the required arguments to the side-effect function very easy.

Comment: If you're using a list comprehension for a side-effect, I'd suggest you'd be wise to look into either map or reduce. https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/enumerables-and-streams.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak to how idiomatic this is, but if you're worried about efficiency, you could always make a struct that implements `Collectable` but doesn't actually do any work.

```
defmodule NoCollect do
  defstruct []
end

defimpl Collectable, for: NoCollect do
  def into(pool) do
    {pool, fn
      expr, {:cont, _} -> expr
      expr, :done -> expr
      _   , :halt -> :ok
    end}
  end
end
```

Then you can use it like so

```
for ..., into: %NoCollect{} do
  # ...
end
```

Then you'll still technically get a comprehension object, but now it will be a trivial `%NoCollect{}` object, no matter how many times the loop runs, rather than actually accumulating then discarding the values.

Comment: Thank you - for large `n` this makes the difference between a machine maxing out of memory, or executing a comprehension with side effects performantly.

Comment: I think the better question is why someone would want to run a comprehension for side-effects only. That seems like it'd be better handled with a map or a reduce or some other function in that family.

Answer (score 2):

If this is about the memory consumption of building up the return for a large `n`, I imagine you'd want to avoid the `Enum.map` over `2..n` as well.

Have you tried using Streams?

```
2..n
|> Stream.map(& &1*&1 + &1)
|> Stream.filter(& &1 <= :math.sqrt(n))
|> Enum.each(& Refrigerator.put(pid, &1, "this is my food"))
```

Comment: Thanks, now I see that the key to the iteration here is `Enum.each`.